# Translate index_id to the name of the index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The system function `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` returns the fragmentation of all indexes on a server.  Instead of names, it returns the `id` of the tables and indexes.  The names of databases, schema's and objects can be found using `db_name`, `object_schema_name`, and `object_name`:

```
select  db_name(ips.database_id)
,       object_schema_name(ips.object_id, ips.database_id)
,       object_name(ips.object_id, ips.database_id)
,       ips.index_id
,       ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
from    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(null, null, null, null, null) ips
```

The function `object_name` does not work for indexes.  A join to `sys.indexes` works, but it's database specific, so you have to run it in a cursor with dynamic SQL.

Is there a better way to translate `index_id` to the name of the index?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` without the database parameter set, why not loop through a list of databases from sys.databases pulled into a temp table and then querying for the index stats with the specific databases.  There's an [extensive script posted here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Maintenance) on this topic.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: Answer link is now broken and refers to Toad's blogs without context.

Answer (score -1):

the system view `dm_db_index_physical_stats` contains a column `object_id`. This is the id of the object(table) in the `sysobjects` table. So you can simply look it up thus:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE id = 'add object id here'
```

`name` will be the table name. Obviously this could be also be turned into an `INNER JOIN` to prevent the additional call.